# Solve this improper integral: $\int_0^1 \ln{(x - 1)} \ dx$

Tags: improper-integrals

$$\int_0^1 \ln{(x - 1)} \ dx$$

I don't know how to solve this integral.

My teacher says the solution is $-1$ but I don't know how to reach this result.

Comment: You forgot $dx$

Comment: Hi, and welcome! I've edited your post to include mathjax formatting; please make sure it says what you intended. Can you please share your thoughts on the problem, and explain what you've tried? For example, do you know how to find an antiderivative of $\ln$?

Comment: It's not even defined on $]0,1[$.

Comment: @GitGud: What does $]a,b[$ mean? I am not familiar with that notation.

Comment: @SujaanKunalan You may know it as $(a,b)$, the open interval. The notation $]a,b[$ is used because $(a,b)$ may look like an ordered pair.

Comment: First, you need to consider the function $\ln(1-x)$, as the function you have isn't defined. Better yet, consider $$\int_0^1\ln(x)\,dx\,.$$ Do you not have any idea how to approach this?

Comment: @SujaanKunalan: It's because you are not born in France. It mean the open interval $(a,b)$.

Comment: Ah, yes I am more accustomed to $(a,b)$. Thanks for the clarification.

Comment: @T.Bongers, I do this lim t->1 [-1/2 ln[(1-x)]^2] which is not -1

Comment: We have: $\int_0^1 \ln{(x - 1)} \ dx=i\pi-1$

Comment: It must be the $\int_0^1\ln(1-x)$ that is $1$, because the value of $\int_0^1\ln(x-1)$ as a definite integration of complex function $\ln(x-1)$ is equal to $-1+\pi i$. And in that case you can use integration by part.

Comment: If the integrand is $\ln(1-x)$ you will get the value $-1$ for the integral.

Comment: Either this is meant to be taken as a complex integral or else it makes no sense as the **real** integrand $\;\log(x-1)\;$ is not even defined on $\;(0,1)\;$ ...

Comment: @DonAntonio : You must consider the integrand as a complex function so it make sense. Consider $\ln z=\ln|z|+i\theta$, then for example $\ln(-1)=\ln(1)+\pi= i\pi i$

Comment: I know that, @FarshadNahangi: thanks. I don't think the OP meant that, though, as the question seems to be pretty elementary...and assuming we already chose a definite branch cut for the complex logarithm (say, the non-positive imaginary axis), then $\;\text{Log}\,(-1)=\log|-1|+i\arg(-1)=\pi i\;$

Answer (score 2):

Hints:

Assuming you meant a real function then it could be $\;\log(1-x)\;$:

$$u=1-x\implies -du=dx\implies$$

$$\int\limits_0^1\log(1-x)\,dx=-\int\limits_{1}^0\log u\,du=\int\limits_0^1\log u\,du=$$

$$=\left.\left(u\log u-u\right)\right|_0^1=-1-\underbrace{\lim_{\epsilon\to 0}\epsilon\log\epsilon}_{=0}=-1$$

Comment: You can't integrate when the function is undefined.

Comment: I know that, @AHH . Thanks a lot. I did *not* integrate an undefined function but a defined one. Read carefully...

Comment: I'm afraid that that your first equality above is wrong, @AHH...and anyway I don't understand what your point is.

Comment: Maybe!. By the way, thanks. @DonAntonio

Comment: Anytime, @AHH...

Answer (score 0):

The function $\log(x-1)$ is not defined on $(0,1)$, just take $x=\tfrac{1}{2}$ and you get a logarithm of a negative number.

Let us suppose then that you wanted to evaluate, 
$$ \int_0^1 \log(1-x) ~ dx $$
You can do this by using infinite series, 
$$ \log(1-x) = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{x^n}{n} \implies  \int_0^1 \log(1-x)~ dx = -\sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \int_0^1 \frac{x^n}{n} ~ dx = - \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} $$
Now you can evaluate the infinite series by telescoping it, 
$$ \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \frac{1}{n(n+1)} = \sum_{n=1}^{\infty} \left\{ \frac{1}{n} - \frac{1}{n+1} \right\} = 1$$
So the integral evaluates to $-1$ as you wanted to show.

Comment: Just wondering, how do you justify the exchange of the sum and integral?